# Silly doubt regarding onto function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, self-learning

> Let function $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be defined as $f(x)=|1-\frac{1}{x}|$. Then is it onto function?

My doubt is that here the codomain doesn't include $0$ but here in the function $0$ is there on $x=1$. So, will it be an onto function? (confusion is created due to this point $(1,0) $  ).

Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Comment: You are correct, but I expect the question was intended to refer to $f$ as mapping to $[0,\infty)$.  With that change it makes sense to ask if it is surjective or not.

Comment: @lulu No, actually it has been given in the test  called for JEE Main.

Comment: It could still be a typo. It's very hard to eliminate typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, $f$ is not a well defined function and the reason has been stated by you. $f(1)$ is not in the codomain.

Comment: So it is not onto function.

Comment: it is not even a function.

Comment: Okay. I understood. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: It is not a (correctly defined) function, hence it is not an onto function. If you change the codomain to $[0,\infty)$ it becomes an onto function (either you solve $f(x)=y$ for each $y\in [0,\infty)$ explicitely or you use the intermediate value theorem).